# How to push the check value and variable value in to json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here i have one form , and one form fields that is checkbox, suppose i am clicking **Ward robe & Lights** and click the submit button means i am taking this value and push to my json format upto now it is working fine,My question is i have to variable suppose in that variable !empty means i want push this value into my json.one more condition also we have to check like suppose in form i am clicking values are Ward robe & Fridge and my **var needtopushval='Fridge';** Fride is two time is the so should not push this varaible into my json

```js
 function rentfunction(){
 var needtopushval=' Lights';
    var arr1 = [];
    var data={
            "rentProperty": {
                            "fullName" : "Some Name"
                            },
            "floorType":[]
        };
                $.each($("input[name='furniture_check']:checked"),function(){
                var furniture = $(this).val();
                arr1.push({"floorTypeName": furniture }); 
                });
    arr1.push({"floorTypeName": needtopushval });

             data.floorType=arr1;
            //or data["floorType"]=arr1;

                console.log(data);
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Ward robe">Ward robe <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Lights">Lights <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fan">Fan <br><br><br>
  
  <button type="button" id="rentBtnSubmit" onclick="rentfunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> My Expected JSON

```
    {
  "rentProperty": {
    "fullName": "Some Name"
  },
  "floorType": [
    {
      "floorTypeName": "Ward robe"
    },
    {
      "floorTypeName": "Lights"
    },
    {
      "floorTypeName": "Fridge"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can direct push the object to the `floorType` using this `data.floorType.push({ __YOUR_OBJECT__})`

Comment: Rohit, your question since *My question is* is unclear. Can you rephrase differently, maybe in two different paragraphs with example input/output?

Comment: @SK Jajoriya, Yes correct i implemented check my code snippet now, the main problem is in form field i am checking Lights and my needtopushval also Lights so two time same  value is pushing to object,but for me need one time only push the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it'll help you to solve your problem

```js
 function rentfunction(){
     var needtopushval='Lights';
     var arr1 = [];
     var data={
            "rentProperty": {
                            "fullName" : "Some Name"
                            },
            "floorType":[]
        };
    // 
     $.each($("input[name='furniture_check']:checked"),function(e)      {
       var furniture = $.trim($(this).val());
       var index=data.floorType.indexOf({"floorTypeName": furniture });
         if(index==-1){
              data.floorType.push({"floorTypeName": furniture });
           }
      });
    var flag=0;
    $.each(data.floorType,function(e){             
         if($.trim(data.floorType[e].floorTypeName) === $.trim(needtopushval)){
           flag=1;
         }
    });
     if(flag==0){
         data.floorType.push({"floorTypeName": $.trim(needtopushval)});
     }
    
    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form>
     <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Ward robe">Ward robe <br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Lights">Lights <br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fan">Fan <br><br><br>
      
      <button type="button" id="rentBtnSubmit" onclick="rentfunction()">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Not correct because suppose i am selecting Ward robe & Fan means that time we have to push  var needtopushval=' Lights'; answer should come like this 
{
  "rentProperty": {
    "fullName": "Some Name"
  },
  "floorType": [
    {
      "floorTypeName": "Ward robe"
    },
    {
      "floorTypeName": "Lights"
    },
    {
      "floorTypeName": "Fan"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps

Code to check the value non empty and weather the value already exist

```
var pos = arr1.map(function(e) {
    return e.floorTypeName;
}).indexOf(furniture);

if (pos == -1 && needtopushval) {
    arr1.push({
        "floorTypeName": needtopushval
    });
}
```

```js
function rentfunction() {
    var needtopushval = ' Lights';
    var arr1 = [];
    var data = {
        "rentProperty": {
            "fullName": "Some Name"
        },
        "floorType": []
    };
    $.each($("input[name='furniture_check']:checked"), function() {
        var furniture = $(this).val();
        if (furniture) {
            arr1.push({
                "floorTypeName": furniture
            });
        }

        //Code to Check weather a value exist and notempty
        var pos = arr1.map(function(e) {
            return e.floorTypeName;
        }).indexOf(furniture);


        if (pos == -1 && needtopushval) {
            arr1.push({
                "floorTypeName": needtopushval
            });
        }

    });

    data.floorType = arr1;
    //or data["floorType"]=arr1;

    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Ward robe">Ward robe <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Lights">Lights <br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="furniture_check" value="Fan">Fan <br><br><br>
  
  <button type="button" id="rentBtnSubmit" onclick="rentfunction()">Submit</button>
</form>
```